# C# Testing - compare list of custom type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, assert, fluent-assertions

I'm trying to write test checking if JSON converter corectly deserialize input to my custom list

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void JSONInput_Changed()
    {
        List<PointOnChart> _expectedPointsOnChart;
        _expectedPointsOnChart = new List<PointOnChart>();
        _expectedPointsOnChart.Add(new PointOnChart { Timestamp = "2020-02-14T09:00:00.000Z", Value1 = 10, Value2 = 20, Value3 = 30 });
        _expectedPointsOnChart.Add(new PointOnChart { Timestamp = "2020-02-14T09:01:00.000Z", Value1 = 11, Value2 = 21, Value3 = 31 });
        _expectedPointsOnChart.Add(new PointOnChart { Timestamp = "2020-02-14T09:02:00.000Z", Value1 = 12, Value2 = 22, Value3 = 32 });
        _expectedPointsOnChart.Add(new PointOnChart { Timestamp = "2020-02-14T09:03:00.000Z", Value1 = 13, Value2 = 23, Value3 = 33 });

        MultipleBarChart multipleBarChartTest = new MultipleBarChart();
        multipleBarChartTest.MeInitialize(DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes);
        string JSONstring = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\slawomirk\source\repos\VIXCharts\iFixMultipleBarChartTests\TestJson.txt");
        multipleBarChartTest.JSONInput = JSONstring;
        List<PointOnChart> resultPointsOnChart = multipleBarChartTest.PointsOnChart;

        //bool areEqual = _expectedPointsOnChart.SequenceEqual(resultPointsOnChart);
        IEnumerable<PointOnChart> resultList;
        resultList = _expectedPointsOnChart.Except(resultPointsOnChart);
        if (resultList.Any())
        {
            Assert.Fail();
        }
    }
```

List contains object of this class

```
public class PointOnChart
{
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
    public double Value1 { get; set; }
    public double Value2 { get; set; }
    public double Value3 { get; set; }
}
```

And this is file I'm reading to deserialize:

> [{"Timestamp":"2020-02-14T09:00:00.000Z","Value1":10,"Value2":20,"Value3":30},
>   {"Timestamp":"2020-02-14T09:01:00.000Z","Value1":11,"Value2":21,"Value3":31},
>   {"Timestamp":"2020-02-14T09:02:00.000Z","Value1":12,"Value2":22,"Value3":32},
>   {"Timestamp":"2020-02-14T09:03:00.000Z","Value1":13,"Value2":23,"Value3":33}]

I tried numerous ways to compare two Lists but all of them fails eg.:
 - Fluent Assertion
 - CollectionAssert

When I inspect both List in debug they are identical.
I know it's probably trivial but I could find any solution online, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the [SequenceEquals overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_SequenceEqual__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) that uses a custom IEqualityComparer? Since you haven't defined a way in `PointOnChart` itself to determine equality, the test framework won't be able to tell if two are the same or not.

Comment: How does `PointOnChart` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the `Equals` method for the `PointOnChart` class, something like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(other, this)) return true;

    var obj = other as PointOnChart;

    if (obj == null) return false;

    return this.Timestamp == obj.Timestamp && this.Value1 == obj.Value1 && this.Value2 == obj.Value2 && this.Value3 == obj.Value3;
}
```

This way the `SequenceEquals` extension method will operate properly.

Comment: You forgot about `GetHashCode()`

Comment: SequenceEquals will only use the Equals method, although, for completeness, yes, we should also implement GetHashCode.

Comment: You should really implement these methods in its own `IEqualityComparer<PointOnChart>` class. Otherwise you could get into awkward problems, especially if you start to derive from this class and others start to call your `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods (like `Dictionary<,>` or LINQ methods like `Distinct()`, `Join()`, etc.).

Comment: Don't agree, I think the class should know how to compare itself, this is useful in lots of situations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of polluting your production code with `Equals` overrides, considering using www.fluentassertions.com and write that statement as:

`resultPointsOnChart.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedPointsOnChart);`

Comment: Totally disagree. I think the class should know how to compare itself, it is useful in lots of places.

Comment: Highly depends on whether that class is supposed to have value semantics or not. If it doesn't (because it's an entity in a domain), then adding `Equals` is going to screw things up. NHibernate for instance will suddenly behave differently when the object that you persist overrides `Equals`. This is orthogonal to what you want in unit tests.

Comment: "screw things up"? Do you know what you are saying? This is actually *required* for NHibernate!

Comment: See https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode

Comment: Only if you map that entity as a component (and thus should have value semantics).

Comment: I've build enterprise systems using NHibernate for almost 15 years, and I can you tell you that overriding Equals is almost always a bad idea. For entities, NHibernate relies on an ID property. And this also aligns really well with similarly named concepts on Domain-Driven Design (Entities, Value Objects). But let's agree to disagree. This topic wasn't about that.

Comment: Well, 25 years for me, and few books written on that... but as I said, nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, i suggest implementing `IEquatable<T>` as well as overriding `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(Object)` like this.

```cs
public class PointOnChart : IEquatable<PointOnChart> {

    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
    public double Value1 { get; set; }
    public double Value2 { get; set; }
    public double Value3 { get; set; }

    public override Int32 GetHashCode() => Timestamp.GetHashCode() ^ Value1.GetHashCode() ^ Value2.GetHashCode() ^ Value3.GetHashCode();

    public override Boolean Equals(Object obj) => Equals(obj as PointOnChart);

    public Boolean Equals(PointOnChart other) => other != null && other.Timestamp == Timestamp && other.Value1.Equals(Value1) && other.Value2.Equals(Value2) && other.Value3.Equals(Value3);

}
```

That'll give you all the comparing you'll need.
Will also make it easier to implement an `IEqualityComparer` or `IEqualityComparer<T>` if you need it later on.